# How to run .net core grpc in docker container?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, grpc

Hi I have created GRPC project using .Net 5. Below is my Docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./*.sln ./
COPY */*.csproj ./
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ${file%.*} && mv $file ${file%.*}; done
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Geography"
RUN dotnet build "Geography.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Geography.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Geography.dll"]
```

I tried to run solution in visual studio using Docker and I see container up and running. I see below ports exposed.

```
 0.0.0.0:32775->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32774->443/tcp
```

I created client application and tried to hit grpc end points as below.

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:32774");
var client = new Geographys.GeographysClient(channel);
```

Here I am getting below error

> Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call.
> HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
> existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
> An error occurred while sending the request. --->
> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
> connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host.. --->

can someone help me to understand the root cause of this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you confident that your .NET code is exposing a non-TLS HTTP endpoint on container port `80` and a TLS HTTP endpoint on `443`?

I suspect it isn't and this would explain why you're unable to access the service through the ports when they're bound to the host (on `32775` and `32774` respectively).

> **NOTE** Your client code tries to access `http://localhost:32774` which possibly maps to the container's TLS endpoint (`:443`) so you'd need to use `https://` and configure a certificate.

If you're running Linux on the host, you can try telnet'ing to those ports to see whether you get a response:

```sh
telnet localhost 32775
telnet localhost 32774
```

If you have [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) (and IMO you should for any gRPC dev), you can try listing methods:

```sh
grpcurl \
-plaintext \
-proto path/to/your.proto \
localhost:32775 \
list

grpcurl \
-plaintext \
-proto path/to/your.proto \
localhost:32774 \
list
```

> **NOTE** I think that's the correct `grpcurl` for both TLS and non-TLS but writing without being able to test

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following code

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
  }
```

in the `appsettings.json` file on the gRPC server side and calling 'http' port instead of 'https' on the gRPC client side should do the trick. In your example that would be:

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:32775");
```